# g++ compiler failed and terrminated with exit code -1

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to make a window inside of SDL2. Each time that I try to compile the code, I receive the message "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++g++.exe build active file' has terminated with exit code -1". I don't know what is causing this message, as when I press show errors it shows that there is no errors inside of the workspace.

I am using g++ as my compiler

Here is the file structure:

[The file structure of the folder, Include contains SDL2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8itTe.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

const int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);

    if(NULL == window)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create window" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Event windowEvent;

    while(true)
    {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if(SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tried changing the path of the SDL header file, thinking that that may be the issue. That didn't work. I then tried to compile on a different computer, thinking that the compiler path on my computer was wrong. That didnt fix the issue.

Comment: How are you linking with the required SDL2 libraries? Are you using CMake and a CMakeLists.txt and the CMake-Tools extension or did you create a Makefile and installed the MakeFileTools extension to did you edit your tasks.json with the correct command line arguments for linking?

Comment: I don't recommend your file structure. The official [VSCode MinGW instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) tell you to install msys2 and have that install MinGW. You should have also installed SDL2 using `pacman` and not have copied any SDL2 files into your workspace folder at all.

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the full compiler output

Comment: @AlanBirtles there is no compiler output because vscode didn't find the compiler probably.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI if that's the case then the error output would show that